# How to configure wsgi application to migrate to django 1.7?

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I'm trying to upgrade from Django 1.6 to 1.7.

When running python manage.py runserver, I got the following error :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'myapp.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module: 'cannot import name get_path_info'
```

Here's the corresponding line in my settings.py :

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'
```

Here's my wsgi.py file :

```
import os

# We defer to a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE already in the environment. This breaks
# if running multiple sites in the same mod_wsgi process. To fix this, use
# mod_wsgi daemon mode with each site in its own daemon process, or use
# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myapp.settings"
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)

from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Any idea to fix it ?

Comment: Looks like `Cling` is causing error. Can you remove `Cling` & try once again?

Comment: @ChillarAnand If I do this, the server starts, but static files aren't served anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of dj_static are you using?

I upgraded to Django 1.7 and my site broke, leading me to your question.

I checked my dj_static version (I had been using 0.0.5 and noticed that the latest release at the time of this writing is [0.0.6](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-static/releases)).

Upon updating dj_static, my site appears to be functioning properly under Django 1.7.

Comment: Yay.  How did you think of this?